# How to convert a Map<String, List<List<String>>> to Map<String, List<String>> using Java 8 functional APIs?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a class like this:

```
class: {
   id: "",
   sub: [{
       type: 1,
       value: ""
   }]
}
```

Now, I want to group class first by id:

```java
class.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(class::id))
```

Then I want flat sub-value to a `List<String>`.  I have the following:

```java
class.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(class::id,
  Collectors.mapping(e ->
    e.sub().stream()
      .filter(v -> v.type().equals(1))
       .map(sub::value),
    Collectors.toList()
  )))
```

This returns a `Map<String, List<List<String>>>`

How can I convert a `Map<String, List<List<String>>>` to `Map<String, List<String>>` using the Java 8 functional API?

Comment: Can I ask `class.stream()` is your original 'class' variable a Map or is it a list?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Map` collector to group by keys and merge the values.

Example (Java 14 & above):

```java
class Test {

    // sample data types
    record Sub ( int type, String value ){}
    record Clazz (String id, List<Sub> sub){}

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // sample data
        List<Clazz> classes = List.of(
            new Clazz("id1",List.of(new Sub(1,"A"),new Sub(2,"B"))),
            new Clazz("id2",List.of(new Sub(3,"C"),new Sub(4,"D"))),
            new Clazz("id1",List.of(new Sub(5,"E"),new Sub(6,"A")))
        );

        Map<String, List<String>> map = classes.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                // key for new map: c.id
                c -> c.id,
                
                // value for new map: c.sub[].value as a list
                c -> c.sub.stream().map(s -> s.value).toList(),
                
                // duplicate value merging (grouping) : merge two value lists, no duplicates
                (v1, v2) -> Stream.concat(v1.stream(), v2.stream()).distinct().toList()
            ));

        // print resulting data
        map.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println(k + "\t->\t" + String.join(",", v)));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
id2 ->  C,D
id1 ->  A,B,E
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a good use case for [`Collectors.flatMapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)):

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = class.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(class::id,
              Collectors.flatMapping(e -> 
                         e.sub().stream()
                                .filter(v -> v.type().equals(1))
                                .map(sub::value),
                         Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Sametcey suggested you can use `flatMap`.
 Whenever you encounter something that uses nested lists (just like your `Map<String, List<List>>`, but it's possible to use it on deeper level like `Map<String, List<List<List>>>`) `flatMap` will help you with that.

It will transform your stream into a single flattened stream. In other words: one list that you can access and manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your sample code, it looks like you want to group elements by unique ID, mapped to all the `sub` values where `type` = 1.  This can be achieved using [`Collectors.groupingBy(classifier, downstream)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)) using a downstream `Collector` which maps and filters the matching `sub` values.

```java
record Sub(int type, String value) { }
record Clazz(String id, List<Sub> sub) { }

List<Clazz> classes = List.of( /* ... */ );

Map<String, List<String>> map = classes.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Clazz::id,
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                        l -> l.stream().flatMap(c -> c.sub().stream())
                                .filter(s -> s.type() == 1)
                                .map(Sub::value)
                                .toList())));
```

`Collectors.collectingAndThen` first collects all values matching a given ID to a `List<Sub>`.  It then streams over that list, filtering and mapping to the values to give a `List<String>` of just the `value` attributes of the `sub` elements of type 1.

For example:

```java
List<Clazz> classes = List.of(
        new Clazz("1", List.of(new Sub(1, "1A"), new Sub(2, "1B"), new Sub(1, "1C"))),
        new Clazz("2", List.of(new Sub(3, "2A"), new Sub(1, "2B"), new Sub(1, "2C"))),
        new Clazz("1", List.of(new Sub(5, "3A"), new Sub(1, "3B"), new Sub(6, "3C")))
);
```

results in:

```
{1=[1A, 1C, 3B], 2=[2B, 2C]}
```